# Serializable attribute in silverlight 4

Tags: silverlight, attributes, serializable

So do we or do we not have a Serializable attribute in silverlight 4? I have some confusing responses on the internet. When I try to use it in my code, i get a namespace error. These are my includes

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
```

I have the assemblies System ,System.Runtime.Serialization added to my project.

A follow up question is, if it is not available in Silverlight how do I correctly serialize a singleton? Since I was planning to use the example given here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable.aspx

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

That's a .NET attribute which you can't use in Silverlight, but you can use DataContract to serialize.

For stand-alone (non-WCF) serialization/deserialization, there are three components which can be used:

System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer (from System.Runtime.Serialization.dll)
System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer (from System.ServiceModel.Web.dll)
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer (from System.Xml.Serialization.dll)

A simple example using the DataContractSerializer:

```
string SerializeWithDCS(object obj)
{
    if (obj == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("obj");
    DataContractSerializer dcs = new DataContractSerializer(obj.GetType());
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    dcs.WriteObject(ms, obj);
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)ms.Position);
}
```

Example from this thread: http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/23161/82135.aspx

Comment: I did use the DataContract to serialize but that means that I can end up with multiple instances of a singleton class.

Comment: @user642770 there's an interface for that, btw; not sure if it exists in SL