# Why is SerializableAttribute not included in the Silverlight version of FCL?

Tags: .net, silverlight, serialization, serializable, fcl

Why is SerializableAttribute not included in the Silverlight version of FCL?

And also, BinaryFormatter is not in there either.

I am not looking for an alternative solution, I am just curious about the fact.

Is binary serialization fundamentally against some of Silverlight's design rules?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Serializable attribute in silverlight 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5381684/serializable-attribute-in-silverlight-4)

Comment: @Preet Sangha: That post wants an alternative solution, I am just curious about the fact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, Silverlight has different permission rules - much harder to get at the private fields. Of course, for the FCL designers I don't think this would be a problem - they could just code that into the runtime (but re-creating a potential way of side-stepping the sandbox).

Perhaps the *biggie* is that Silverlight doesn't need (or want) to support "remoting", which is the main reason it has to exist in the main .NET BCL. Of course, remoting is out of fashion *generally*, but needs to be in core .NET for backwards compatibility.

A third reason could well be the very nature of `BinaryFormatter`; many classes in SL have different implementations inside the SL runtime, to account for different features and available types / security / etc. This makes it virtually impossible to have it **wire compatible** with the core .NET runtime. So you wouldn't be able to share it with your server code.

Overall, then, it makes great sense to just cut it. For app<===>server, contract-based serializers exist; and other (dare I say: better) binary serializers are available that avoid all these problems (i.e. are fully portable).