# how can i mark class serializable defined in silverlight project?

Tags: c#, silverlight, serialization

how can i mark  class serializable defined in silverlight project. i m trying to add assembly reference of using System.Runtime.Serialization but still its not allowing me to mark a class serializable

Comment: See the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5381684/serializable-attribute-in-silverlight-4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>Are you just trying to attribute your type with the `Serializable` attribute?</strike>

That exists in the `System` namespace rather than `System.Runtime.Serialization`. Have you imported the `System` namespace? See [SerializableAttribute class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serializableattribute.aspx)

Unless I've missed something, in which case your question probably needs more detail.

Edit: See [this question about Serialization in Silverlight 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5381684/serializable-attribute-in-silverlight-4)